# Ember without using rest url

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have a strange requirement. 
1) the backend server talks in terms of custom JSON. We need to marshall and unmarshall this JSON in the ember REST adapter. We are not going to use Ember to convert JSON to object and vice versa.
2) Our back end is JAX-RS. Where we are allowed to give single url at class level. @Path \customer is allowed. the custom framework does not allow \customer\create or \customer\1 or anything of this sort.
3) We are having big debate whether ember can help in this scenario as we will not be able to make full use of ember.
4) What we are thinking of doing is define requestType (Create, update, query etc.) and send reuestType as another element in JSON structure.
5) Is this possible at RESTadapter or controller level. if yes, than which one is better place.

Answer (score 0):

You would't be able to use `Ember Data` out-of-the-box. Not converting the JSON to objects would pretty much render `Ember` (or any other client side framework) useless.

I'm struggling the understand your intention for using a framework like `Ember`.

I'm personally working a project that uses Ember without Ember Data at the moment (because of API limitations). We only need to do our own get/create/update/delete handling, which is pretty easy using the `Ember.RSVP.Promise` implementations.